# How to create a new pipewire virtual device that to combines an real input and output into a new input?

Tags: linux, audio, microphone, pipewire

My problem is this: I'm talking to some friends via voice chat and at some point I'd also like to mix some music into it. So my current setup is this:

```
Microphone (Input device) -> Voice software
Music player -> Headphones (Output device)
```

I'd like to have this:

```
Music player -> Headphones

Music player -\
               -> ? -> Voice software
Microphone   -/
```

I've had a look at the [Pipewire wiki](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/) quite a bit and especially the part about [Virtual-Devices](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Virtual-Devices#virtual-sink) seemed to be very relevant but after playing around with a lot of `pw-loopback` I eventually gave up.

In the end, I think I'll need to end up with a virtual input device so that it's even selectable in my recording applications.

Is this even the right approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to mix your voice input (mic) and the output of music player, then the setup would be like this:

```
Music player -\
               -> Combined Sink/Source -> Virtual Microphone -> Voice software
Microphone   -/
```

Here is the walktrough:

#### 1. Create the combined-sink interface

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink media.class=Audio/Sink sink_name=my-combined-sink channel_map=stereo
```

#### 2. Create a Virtual Microphone

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink media.class=Audio/Source/Virtual sink_name=my-virtualmic channel_map=front-left,front-right
```

#### 3. Link your microphone & the music player output into the combined sink

Note: The microphone interface name & the music player output interface name may be different. Run `pw-link -o` to show list of the outputs.

```
pw-link spotify:output_FL my-combined-sink:playback_FL
pw-link spotify:output_FR my-combined-sink:playback_FR

pw-link alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo:capture_FL  my-combined-sink:playback_FL
pw-link alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo:capture_FR  my-combined-sink:playback_FR
```

#### 4. Link your combined sink to the virtual microphone

```
pw-link my-combined-sink:monitor_FL my-virtualmic:input_FL
pw-link my-combined-sink:monitor_FR my-virtualmic:input_FR
```

Now you can tell the voice software to make use this virtual microphone or set the virtual microphone as the default voice input.

Comment: Please, change point 3 to mention both `pw-link -o` and `pw-link -i`. As it currently stands it confuses, because the `-o` won't show `*playback*` nodes, so it would look as if they're missing.

Comment: You can link all your microphones and it will work just fine. You might save yourself an hour trying to find out why it does not work because you picked the wrong microphone, like I did.

Comment: While you still need the command-line to create the virtual devices, you can link them using a GUI. I personally recommend using [qpwgraph](https://github.com/rncbc/qpwgraph), as it is very intuitive. There is also [helvum](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/helvum), but I find it more difficult to use.

Answer (score 1):

use pw-link to conect stuff (check out "pw-link -h").
an alternative GUI way would be to use Carla.
there is also the Helvum GUI created especificly for Pipewire

Comment: Thanks, however I'm still unclear as to how I'd even set up my devices in the first place. Which loopbacks do I need to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a scripted version of the answer from Pujianto. This will create a combined virtual mic with another application (which is assumed to be putting out stereo, uniquely named, and greppable).

e.g. `combine_audio.sh spotify`

The script will also remove any null sinks that are active, so be warned, but I think that isn't so common in normal use? I use this with Skype and OBS so I can chat with people and stream application/game audio as well as my mic, without looping their audio in. You may need to restart stuff to have the mic show up, but once it's there you can hot-swap applications without any problem.

You also need to check your mic's name, e.g. the script below uses my webcam.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

SINK_NAME=combined-app-sink
VIRTUAL_MIC_NAME=my-virtualmic
MIC_SOURCE=alsa_input.usb-046d_Logitech_StreamCam_901DCE45-02.analog-stereo

results=$(pw-link -o | grep ${1})
IFS=$'\n' read -ra ADDR -d $'\0' <<< "$results"

# Unload if exists
pactl unload-module module-null-sink

# Make new sinks
pactl load-module module-null-sink media.class=Audio/Sink sink_name=$SINK_NAME channel_map=stereo >> /dev/null
pactl load-module module-null-sink media.class=Audio/Source/Virtual sink_name=$VIRTUAL_MIC_NAME channel_map=front-left,front-right >> /dev/null

# Extract app name
IFS=':'
read -a APP_STR <<< ${ADDR[0]}
echo "Linking app ${APP_STR} to ${SINK_NAME}"
pw-link "${APP_STR}":output_FL $SINK_NAME:playback_FL
pw-link "${APP_STR}":output_FR $SINK_NAME:playback_FR

echo "Linking $MIC_SOURCE to ${SINK_NAME}"
pw-link $MIC_SOURCE:capture_FL  $SINK_NAME:playback_FL
pw-link $MIC_SOURCE:capture_FR  $SINK_NAME:playback_FR

echo "Creating virtual mic: $VIRTUAL_MIC_NAME"
pw-link $SINK_NAME:monitor_FL $VIRTUAL_MIC_NAME:input_FL
pw-link $SINK_NAME:monitor_FR $VIRTUAL_MIC_NAME:input_FR
```

Could combine with https://askubuntu.com/questions/355082/pulseaudio-loopback-unload-audio-output-devices to make unloading more intelligent.

Comment: So you just run this script automatically at system startup?

Comment: The app needs to be running before you create the interface I think. I run it on demand since I only need to use it for video calling.